# MS Access Report no data output

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have problem with this line:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
   DoCmd.OpenReport "Daily Report", AcView.acViewPreview, , "rDate =#" & txtDate & "#"
End Sub
```

I was trying to make a printable daily report based on the value of the date from txtDate.

Comment: Assuming the syntax is correct and the source tables have data - what is the value of `txtDate` when the line executes? It's very likely the data is being converted incorrectly. Try passing the date through the [SQLDate](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html) function - `"rDate =" & SQLDate(txtDate )`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Hi there! The syntax is correct and the source tables do contain some data. When the txtDate line is executed it is suppose to take the various data that have the value of the (txtDate) for instance ("19/06/2018") will show different names associated with that data.
I've tried the SQLDate but it shows "Complie error: Sub or Function not defined"
`DoCmd.OpenReport "Daily Report", AcView.acViewPreview, , "rDate =" & SQLDate(txtDate)`

Comment: Does your rdate data include time information? If it does your query won't probably pull anything if someone put in a date only.

Comment: @Minty Hi there! I've just check the table and the format is set to "dd-mmm-yy" so I don't think time information was added. And additionally just to make sure, I've created a combo box based on the collumn but it still won't show any data.

Comment: Yes, it will show that error - click on the link in my comment and copy the `SQLDate` VBA function code into your project to use it.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook It works! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to include a timepart:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Daily Report", AcView.acViewPreview, , "rDate >= DateValue(" & txtDate & ") And rDate < DateAdd('d', 1, DateValue(" & txtDate & "))"
```